# Can't install pangox-compat with apt-get

Tags: 14.04, drivers, apt, package-management

I can't install `pangox-compat` package (needed by my printer driver, [Canon MF4120](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf4120.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1506758&os=Linux%20(64-bit)&language=EN)) using `apt-get`. Package exists and the corrisponding repo is enabled:

```
$ apt-cache madison pangox-compat
pangox-compat | 0.0.2-4ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources

$ sudo apt-get update
[...]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
[...]

$ sudo apt-get install pangox-compat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pangox-compat
```

I could download the package and install it using dpkg, but I would not mix the using of `dpkg` and `apt-get`

I have Lubuntu 14.04.1

Answer (score 3):

install it via `sudo apt-get install libpangox-1.0-dev`

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the source package of pangox-compat for 14.04 (Source Package: pangox-compat (0.0.2-4ubuntu1) ).

   ```
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pangox-compat/pangox-compat_0.0.2.orig.tar.xz
   ```
2. Extract the archive that you downloaded.

   ```
   tar -xJvf pangox-compat_0.0.2.orig.tar.xz
   ```
3. Install pangox-compat into a system directory.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential make    
   cd pangox-compat-0.0.2  
   ./configure  
   make  
   sudo make install # installs pangox-compat into a system directory
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`pangox-compat` is a *source* package. [The binary packages built from it](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pangox-compat/0.0.2-4ubuntu1) (the ones you can install using `apt-get install`) are `libpangox-1.0-0` and `libpangox-1.0-dev`. If you need to build something from source, install `libpangox-1.0-dev`. If not, `libpangox-1.0-0` is sufficient.